# Random Number Generator (rand) isn't Random?

Tags: c++, random

I'm generating mazes, I can only pick the first or last column. And I can only choose an even row (if you start the row index at 1). I have the correct logic, except that the maze start position isn't random. If I generate 50 mazes, that are all 20x20, all starting positions will be the same. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
void Maze::generatePath()
{
    int startingColumn = -1;
    int startingRow = -1;

    srand (time(NULL));

    int side = rand() % 2;
    startingColumn = (width - 1) * side; // will get first or last column

    int row = rand() % height; // 0 -> height - 1

    if(row % 2 == 0) // even, add one, or subtract if last row
    {
        if(row + 1 >= width)
            startingRow = row - 1;
        else
            startingRow = row + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        startingRow = row; // odd, keep it
    }

    grid[startingRow][startingColumn] = ' '; // starting character is blank
}
```

I call this method every time I generate a new maze. This code is to get the starting position. I haven't written the rest.

Comment: "Random" numbers could never be totally random, right?

Comment: I fully understand that. It does change each run, but 300 zeros in a row for a single run? I doubt it.

Comment: Do you mean generating 20 mazes by calling `Maze::generatePath()` 20 times in a single program invocation, or by invoking the program 20 times?

Comment: Invoking the method 20 times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only call `srand` once when your program starts. By calling it over and over in the same second, you keep resetting the random number generator to the same state.

Comment: You were right. Will accept in a second. I don't understand how its the same state though? Each time time() is called, it will contain a different time -> therefore I thought a different seed value.

Comment: No, each time `time` is called, during the same second, the time will be the same. The `time` function has a resolution of one second.

Comment: If you want, you can use `srand(rand() ^ time(NULL);` and then it doesn't matter how often or how rarely you call it, as long as you call it at least once before you start using it.

Comment: Sorry for keeping this going, but does calling rand() each time reset the "internal seed value"? Because setting srand to (e.g.) 40 seconds once, I would assume would be just as random as setting it to 40 seconds multiple times, unless rand() changes it.

Comment: The whole point of a settable seed is that, if you *do* need to reproduce a given sequence, you can do so by using the same seed.  (This is often necessary for simulations.)

Answer (score 2):

If you need better randomness you might use as random seed something better than time(NULL).
It may be for example /dev/random(or more practically /dev/urandom) device on unix-like systems.
For really hardcore cases some real radnomness based on physical phenomena might be desired.
For instance this one: http://photonics.anu.edu.au/qoptics/Research/qrng.php

Comment: All true, but the guy's trying to generate mazes, not do crypto. He just needs basic sanity.